# Python Using the Output of A Function Inside of Another Function

Tags: python, function, csv, variables, pdf

Sorry to post another repetitive question, but I have been dealing with this fundamental concept, and despite trying to learn from others' examples I still do not understand it.

What I am trying to do is get the contents of a PDF using PyPDF2 and write them to a CSV, and I am slowly building and testing my program step by step. I am at the point where I want my program to do two things:

1 grab the text from the pdf file

2. output the grabbed text to a single entry in a csv file.

Now here is where my lack of fundamental programming concepts starts to show. Here's the code:

```
 import csv
 import os
 import PyPDF2

 os.chdir('C:/Users/User/Desktop')

 def getText(happy_file):
     pdf_file_obj = open(happy_file, 'rb')
     pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file_obj)
     pdf_reader.numPages #optional
     page_obj = pdf_reader.getPage(0)
     return page_obj.extractText()

 def writeToCSV(happy_file):
     output_file = open('myfinalfile.csv', 'w', newline ='')
     output_writer = csv.writer(output_file)
     output_writer.writerow([str(getText())])
     output_file.close()
```

I have two functions to accomplish this task getText and writeToCSV. My goal is to program it such that all I need to do is call writeToCSV('anyfile.pdf') and have it use both functions to extract the data and put it into the csv. happy_file is currently the argument for both functions but I know that needs to change. I am thinking that I need a third main() function that incorporates both functions in a way that the variables are contained inside main(). That might be the fundamental aspect that I am not seeing. Another hunch is that there has to be a way to make the return of getText a usable variable in writeToCSV (actually that is the whole purpose of this post). I have used the 'global' in front of a variable before to access variables in other functions but I have heard that it is a bad idea.

I get that I could just make it one function but as things get more complex (namely I want to loop through a bunch of pdfs), I would like to have my program in smaller chunks, each representing a step of the way. Maybe I am just really bad at understanding functions. Maybe seeing my actual code reformatted in the correct way will make it "click" for me.

Figuring this out would be a great step in the right direction of writing well structured programs rather than just one huge list of directions for the computer to carry out.

Here is a list of other posts I researched:

[Python - Passing a function into another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349332/python-passing-a-function-into-another-function)

[using the output of a function as the input in another function python new to coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049876/using-the-output-of-a-function-as-the-input-in-another-function-python-new-to-co)

[Python - output from functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052793/python-output-from-functions)

[Python: accessing returned values from a function, by another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088457/python-accessing-returned-values-from-a-function-by-another-function)

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Do you need a way to get what you have to work properly, or are you looking for a better/different way to solve your problem altogether?

Comment: @AndrewMcKernan I just need a way to make it work properly in order to help cement my understanding how how to use variables from one function in another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `happy_file` into the `getText` function within `writeToCSV` function.

You can then call `writeToCSV` as shown at the bottom of the code example.

```
 import csv
 import os
 import PyPDF2

 os.chdir('C:/Users/User/Desktop')

 def getText(happy_file):
     pdf_file_obj = open(happy_file, 'rb')
     pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file_obj)
     pdf_reader.numPages #optional
     page_obj = pdf_reader.getPage(0)
     return page_obj.extractText()

 def writeToCSV(happy_file):
     output_file = open('myfinalfile.csv', 'w', newline ='')
     output_writer = csv.writer(output_file)
     output_writer.writerow([str(getText(happy_file))])
     output_file.close()

writeToCSV("anyfile.pdf")
```

Alternatively, if for whatever reason you'd prefer a `main()` function you could do it like this:

```
 import csv
 import os
 import PyPDF2

 os.chdir('C:/Users/User/Desktop')

 def getText(happy_file):
     pdf_file_obj = open(happy_file, 'rb')
     pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file_obj)
     pdf_reader.numPages #optional
     page_obj = pdf_reader.getPage(0)
     return page_obj.extractText()

 def writeToCSV(happy_file):
     output_file = open('myfinalfile.csv', 'w', newline ='')
     output_writer = csv.writer(output_file)
     output_writer.writerow([str(getText(happy_file))])
     output_file.close()

 def main():
     writeToCSV("anyfile.pdf")

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Comment: sorry I was away for a bit. Thanks for replying I will try this out now!